# Form onsubmit in dynamic iframe do not get triggered

Tags: javascript

## Update

the problem is not the iframe, the problem is the form not submitting by the onsubmit function that posts json. The goal is to dynamically create an iframe that redirects using a form post to another URL with the json content of the script tag above.

## Original

I have the following on a sample website:

```
<script data-dashboard="true" type="application/json">
    {
    "title":"Serverless Identity"
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let dashboardConfiguration = document.querySelector("script[data-dashboard=\"true\"]");
    if (dashboardConfiguration) {
        let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        let model = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(dashboardConfiguration.innerHTML.trim()));
    
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        doc.open()
        doc.writeln(`<form id="form" action="https://localhost:44338/dashboard/" method="POST" target="_self"></form>`)
        doc.close();


        iframe.onload = () => {
           

            let form = doc.getElementById("form");
             
            form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
                console.log(model);
                e.preventDefault();
                // construct an HTTP request
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                 
                // send the collected data as JSON
                xhr.send(model);

                xhr.onloadend = function () {
                    // done
                };
            });
            form.submit();


        }
    };

</script>
```

I also tried with `onsubmit` with the same result that it does a normal submit.
[image]

Comment: The `onload` event for IFRAMEs is not reliable. Also, you should not use arrow functions for event listeners - try `onsubmit` with a normal function (something like `<form onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit(event)">` and then return **false** in this function)

Comment: none of your suggestions changed anything.

Comment: So you are creating a form, adding a submit handler to that form, submit that form from script, and then you make an AJAX request inside the submit handler. Why? Why not just make the AJAX request, and be done with it, what’s the purpose of this form …?

Comment: You cant make the page redirect without the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible,

when using `form.submit()` any onsubmit handlers will not trigger, as per spec.

I used a different approach og sending a normal form submit using form encoded values with the hole payload in one hidden field and deserialized it on serverside.

Answer (score 0):

When you have created iframe then that it is loaded and then you are binding onload instead of that you should use DOMNodeInserted event on body when iframe is appended to the body like

```
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        let model = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(dashboardConfiguration.innerHTML.trim()));
document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
//write your logic here
});
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Comment: Updated the question to be more specific about the problem. The problem is not about the unload.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2RSPN5BUEL5 You can check this approach to get your result

Comment: It is doing normal form submit, not a json post.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `iframe.onload = () => { }`. Check the chrome `network` tab. The form url `https://localhost:44338/dashboard/` gets triggered.

```
<script data-dashboard="true" type="application/json">
    {
    "title":"Serverless Identity"
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let dashboardConfiguration = document.querySelector("script[data-dashboard=\"true\"]");
    if (dashboardConfiguration) {
        let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        let model = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(dashboardConfiguration.innerHTML.trim()));

        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        doc.open()
        doc.writeln(`<form id="form" action="https://localhost:44338/dashboard/" method="POST" target="_self"></form>`)
        doc.close();

        let form = doc.getElementById("form");

        form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            console.log(model);
            e.preventDefault();
            // construct an HTTP request
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

            // send the collected data as JSON
            xhr.send(model);

            xhr.onloadend = function () {
                // done
            };
        });
        form.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, its triggeret, but with normal form submit, not the xhr json post that i wanted.